# Placing objects below the ground in AR Quick Look on iOS

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, quicklook, arquicklook

I am working on a project that will display objects below the ground using AR Quick Look. However, the AR mode seems to bring everything above the ground based on the bounding box of the objects in the scene.

I have tried using the USDZ directly and composing a simple scene in Reality Composer with the object or with a simple cube with the exact same result. AR preview mode in Reality Composer is showing the object below the ground or below an image anchor correctly. However, if I export the scene as a .reality file and open it in using AR Quick Look, it brings the object above the ground as well.

Is there a way to achieve showing an object below the detected horizontal plane or image (horizontal) using AR Quick Look?

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue a year later. I have submitted feedback to Apple. I suggest you do too. I have suggested adding a checkbox to keep Y axis persistent. My assumption is this behaves this way to prevent the object from colliding with the ground, but I don't think it's necessary. It's just a limitation right now.